# What is better approach to dispose Brush in User Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it better approach to use a new Brush in Paint event i.e

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(129, 242, 121))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {    
            e.Graphics.FillPath(b, path[i]);
        }
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

or define once at top and dispose in Dispose Method i.e

```
SolidBrush _brush;
protected SolidBrush Brush {
    get {
        if (_brush == null)
            _brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(129, 242, 121));
        return _brush;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't see any reason to create new instance every time OnPaint is called, so second approach is better.

Comment: Use the second method and freeze the brush since you don't plan on changing it.

Comment: @BryanAnderson Winforms brush isn't freezable.

Answer (score 19):

Creating and destroying drawing objects like pens and brushes is very cheap, takes about a microsecond.  A very small fraction of the cost of the code that actually does the drawing, typically measured in milliseconds.  You should therefore avoid storing them, that just takes up precious space in the operating system GDI object heap, a resource that needs to be shared by all running processes.  The only drawing object that's expensive to create is a font.  However, Winforms solves this by caching fonts internally.

Make it consistent, always apply the *using* statement to drawing objects you create.

Comment: Hans Passant, can you please point me to the document which states the creation and destruction costs of gdi objects?

Comment: I just measured it.  So can you.

Answer (score 8):

Use predefined [Brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brushes.aspx) if you can (and do not dispose them). If you can't I suggest do not create your brushes on every paint but cache them:

```
IDictionary<Color, Brush> SolidBrushes; //... cache
Brush GetSolidBrush(Color color) {
    if(color.IsSystemColor) 
        return GetSystemBrush(color);
    Brush result = null;
    if(!SolidBrushes.TryGetValue(color, out result)) {
        result = new SolidBrush(color);
        SolidBrushes.Add(color, result);
    }
    return result;
}
Brush GetSystemBrush(Color color) {
    return SystemBrushes.FromSystemColor(color);
}
```

ADDITION:  The best answer on this question may be "depends on task". The brush creation is expensive, because of the brushes themselves (it is managed wrapper on unmanaged GDI+ object), and also because of the garbage collection with all those brushes on every Paint event. So if you use multiple brushes it is better to cache them (of course the cached brushes should be disposed on disposing of owner control or on skin changing). But if you use only one brush (the first case) thr cache is not needed - only use the brush in using block

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of performance I would prefer creating one brush and dispose it in the Dispose method.